# Не создается архив

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

Используется библиотека DotNetZip. Хочу добавить папку со всеми файлами и вложенными папками... в архив:

```
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddDirectory(@"c:\Windows\Temp\TempFolder", @"c:\ProgramData\FolderToZIP\");
            zip.Save("MyZip.zip");
        }
```

Ошибок нет, архив не создан. Можете подсказать в чем ошибка?

Comment: `zip.Save("MyZip.zip");` пробовали задать тут абсолютный путь?

Comment: нет, не пробовал.

Comment: так попробуйте.

Comment: В общем, нет разницы.

Comment: Архив создался, но в нем структура папок как в полном абсолютном пути, что я указал.

Comment: 1. Вы используете очень специфичную директорию для архивации, а именно c:\Windows\Temp - эта папка как минимум защищена правами доступа, а значит запускать приложение надо как минимум с правами администратора. 2. `AddDirectory` принимает первым значением - путь до директории, а вторым - расположение внутри архива, в вашем случае это еще один не очень понятный путь..

Comment: Этот путь я получил используя метод Path.GetTempPath(). Так что права есть. Второй пункт не понял

Comment: EvgeniyZ, спасибо. Понял вас и действительно, открыли свет на мою ошибку. Спасибо, все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте убрать во втором параметре последний слеш. Если не помогает, вот еще можно попробовать:

```
zip.AddSelectedFiles("*", @"c:\Windows\Temp\TempFolder", @"c:\ProgramData\FolderToZIP", true);
zip.Save("MyZip.zip");
```

UPDATE:

```
using (ZipFile zf = new ZipFile())
{
   zf.AddDirectory(@"D:\Users\desk\Documents\ttt", @"ttt\");
   zf.Save("MyZip.zip");
}
```

Создается архив в папке `Debug`, с именем `MyZip.zip`, в котором структура: папка ttt, в которой все файлы из архивируемой папки.

Comment: Этот пример вы проверяли?

Comment: Пример кода, я использовал ранее, да. Насчет убрать слеш в конце вашего примера - нет.

Comment: Не создается архив у меня. Если указать абсолютный путь "C:\ProgramData\FolderToZIP\MyZip.zip" вместо "MyZip.zip", то архив создается, но в нем(архиве) структура подпапок "ProgramData\FolderToZIP\"

Comment: Сейчас скачаю либу и попробую. Может они поменяли что-то...

Comment: У меня все создается, даже с вашим кодом из примера. Просто когда указывается `.Save("MyZip.zip");` архив появляется в директории Release или Debug проекта. Но я пробовал на других папках, не в Temp и не в ProgramData...